# Write directories, subdirectories and file names to .txt file

Tags: linux, filenames, command, directory-structure, text

I am looking for a command that will write the names of all directories, subdirectories and file names to a text file.

Example format:

```
directory1
|_subdirectory1
| |_filename1.mp4
|_subdirectory2
| |_filename2.txt
| |_filename3.jpg
|
directory2
|
...
```

So the text file will only just show what the directory, subdirectories and file names are. The lines dont have to exist but it graphically gives a better view. Not sure if that part is possible or not.

Thx!

Comment: Have you tried `tree DirName | tee file.txt`, `tree DirName > file.txt` or `tree DirName -o file.txt`?

Comment: tree DirName > file.txt  <---- this works! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tree` command with `-o` option.

For example to output contents of /home to file.txt

```
tree /home -o file.txt
```

You will probably need to install `tree` package, since it is usually not installed by default.

There are other options available which you can see with:

```
tree --help
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that the output file has this symbol "00' on top and '1B' on bottom (tried to copy and paste the symbol but it doesnt appear in the comment) in every line. How can that be removed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean shows in file, can you paste part of the output to your question, to see how it looks

Comment: I think he's talking about excape characters. When I use `-o` and open the result file in `less`, the output has escape chars all over; `ESC[01;34m/usr/share/vimESC[00m`. Redirecting with `>` doesn't produce those.

Comment: Option `-n` disables the coloration.