# Using 'TREE' for sub-subdirectories

Tags: linux, directory, rename, tree

Is it possible to use `tree` to create several output files without being cd ~/ into the directory I want to create a `tree` file?

For example, I have a directory called `parent-dir`.

Inside of `parent-dir` are subdirectories titled `a`, `b`, `c` to `z` and one also titled `0-9`.

Inside of those subdirectories are more subdirectories that are titled at **random** using lower/upper case, numbers and some special characters. **(It is at this level I want to create a `tree` .txt output file)**

---

Here is the directory structure:

```
parent-dir ( <-- I will be cd ~/ here and run cmd from here)
|_a
| |_ahgfVFCJC6.h78 ( <-- cmd should create a tree titled ahgfVFCJC6.h78.txt)
| | |_file.jpg
| | |_file.mp4
| |  
| |_a34grBVFHEwerv ( <-- cmd should create a tree titled a34grBVFHEwerv.txt)
|   |_file.txt
|   |_file.mp3
|
|_b
| |_bhlHKH.7tbh ( <-- cmd should create a tree titled bhlHKH.7tbh.txt)
|   |_file.png
|   |_file.txt
```

...and so on...

```
The .txt files created using `tree`:

ahgfVFCJC6.h78.txt
a34grBVFHEwerv.txt
bhlHKH.7tbh.txt

should be outputted in a specified directory (example: ~/Desktop/Tree)
```

I am hoping to run a command while in `parent-dir` because in `a` alone there are thousands of directories like `ahgfVFCJC6.h78` (but named differently). Having to cd into each of those sub-subdirectories would take far too much time.

Comment: That's a bit odd question, seeing that you _have_ accepted an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/737121/write-directories-subdirectories-and-file-names-to-txt-file), where your goal was accomplished, allegedly with my advice. As that wasn't the answer that resolved your issue, you actually _should_ have accepted your _own_ answer - that's perfectly fine :-) If you get advice, you test it and it doesn't help, you should edit the question and add the result. That way your question is up-to-date, so everyone can see we're not there yet.

Comment: As for doing something wrong - I wouldn't say so. If you're used to discussion forum format, Q&A site format can feel a bit odd. You can think of this as a remote support service - the only diff is that nobody's getting paid for this :-D I'd really recommend taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), at least the Asking- and Answering -sections. That does tell you just about everything there is to know about how these sites work.

Comment: will do. thank you.

Comment: @Panki I realized what I was doing wrong by not accepting answers. It's been taken care of now. I also updated this post to provide a better example of what it is I am trying to accomplish. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I updated the original post to provide more details. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh`:

```
for d (parent-dir/*/*(N/)) (cd -- $d && tree) > output-dir/$d:t.txt
```

Comment: im getting a syntax error on the parenthesis.

Comment: @linuxuser24569, from `zsh`?

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with zsh. I just installed it but not sure how to access it.

Comment: @linuxuser24569, the same way you access bash or any other shell, by running it in a terminal emulator. From within another shell, run `zsh`. To make it your login shell instead of `bash`, look at `chsh` or `passwd -s` depending on the system.

Comment: ok, i got zsh to work. this command makes 1 .txt file though and has all of the directories merged. i need a .txt file for each of the directories. if you look at my original post, i will be cd ~ into parent-dir, i will run a command there that will need to go into a/ and then tree a .txt file for ahgfVFCJC6.h78 (called ahgfVFCJC6.h78.txt), then go to the next one in a/ and so on and on, once alll those directories are tree'd into .txt files then it should go into b/ and do the same.

Comment: @linuxuser24569, so a text file for each subdir of each subdir of parent-dir? No just for each subdir of parent-dir? What if two dirs in to two separate subdirs of parent-dir have the same name?

Comment: you're right subdir of subdir of parentdir. once its down to that level there are no two directories that have the same name. the command should output the .txt using the name of the subdir.

Comment: I edited my original post to add more details.

Comment: hey, i just seen that you edited your answer. this works! out of curiousity, what will happen if later on the directory changes and adds 2 new files, and deletes 3 older files. will running this create a new copy, or will it concatenate?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cd to directory to use tree command on it, and you can specify multiple directories to use `tree` on them at the same time.

```
tree /dir1 /dir2 /dir3 -o /some/other/path/outputfile -n
```

also if you want to use stdout redirection like `>` or `>>` you can specify a path there also

```
tree /dir1 /dir2 /dir3 -n > /some/other/path/outputfile
```

If you have some file that has paths you want to check you can do something like following to create outputfile in each dir.

```
for i in $(cat filewithdirs); do tree "$i" -o "$i/outputfile"; done
```

If you want to get paths of all subdirectories in the parentdir you can use something like this

```
tree parentdir/ -L 1 -fid
```

This will print all first level subdirectories in parentdir with no indentation and with their path

- -L option specifies how many levels deep do you want to go
- -f options specified to print path prefix
- -i specifies to not use indentation
- -d specifies to only list directories
- -o specifies to use outputfile instead of stdout

Comment: i would have to specify all the directories i want to create a tree file with then wouldnt i? that would be a massively long command. theres thousands of these directories I want to create their own tree.txt file with.

Comment: how are you going through directories you want to run `tree` command against, you are asking ambiguous questions without ever providing any example of the commands or scripts you are running

Comment: then use a for loop or something similar and output the file in the same dir you are running tree command against, nobody knows what you are doing and how are you feeding data into the commands. you need to give some examples if you want people to give you something more precise, not just in this question, but all the questions you asked.

Comment: let me edit my original post.

Comment: It does, yes, and you would have to, yes. You need to construct some kind of loop if you want each directory `tree` to be output in a separate file. There are many roads to Rome, no single one is the "correct" one - only what best suits your needs and capabilities. Posting your scripts here, with explanations what you expect to happen and what actually happens, is a good way to learn. Practically every time I post one, I get valuable advice on what can I do to make them work more efficiently, pointers to what pitfalls my approach has etc.

Comment: Friend, please don't add info in comments. Do [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737234/edit) your question instead. That way it's up-to-date and the relevant info is readily available. Trying to keep track of the situation from comments is well-night impossible. As for the question - if the task was mine, yes. As far as I can see @ralz has given you pretty good steps. `ls > filewithdirs` gives you the list of directories you can use in a loop as input for `tree`. Without knowing the exact situation and need it's not possible to give you exact script, only help you write one.

Comment: @ralz I updated my post, does it help in creating a loop? I am not sure on how to create a loop myself unfortunately.